# Finding the expectation of 2 consecutive elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, binomial-theorem

I have

```
mylist = [a, b, c, d]
```

and I want to get:

```
[p*a+(1-p)*b, p*b+(1-p)*c, p*c+(1-p)*d]
```

right now what I am doing is this:

```
somelist = []   
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if i+1<len(mylist):
        expectedVal = (1-p)*mylist[i]+p*mylist[i+1]
        somelist.append(expectedVal)
```

is there a cleverer way to not get an "out of index" exception when the loop goes for its last iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind, the simplest modification to your code would be to iterate up to one less than the length of `mylist`:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
    expectedVal = (1-p)*mylist[i]+p*mylist[i+1]
    somelist.append(expectedVal)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip which will stop at the shortest list:

```
for v1, v2 in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    somelist.append((1-p)*v1+p*v2)
```

And you can turn it into a list comprehension:

```
somelist = [(1-p)*v1 + p*v2 for v1, v2 in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])]
```